# Program to print first m prime numbers in the first n positive integers

Tags: java, performance, primes, solver, prime-factoring

Write a program to generate and print first m prime numbers in the first n positive integers.

Example:
n=10,m=2
In a range of 1-10 natural numbers, I have to generate m=2(2 positive prime numbers)
Input:10 2
Output:2 3

My Code :
**Note=Try to answer in java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main5{
static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 static boolean isPrime(int n){
     //since 0 and 1 is not prime return false.
     if(n==1||n==0) return false;

   //Run a loop from 2 to n-1
     
   for(int i=2; i<=n/2; i++){
       
       // if the number is divisible by i, then n is not a prime number.
       if(n%i==0)return false;
   }
   //otherwise, n is a prime number.
   return true; }

public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       int n=sc.nextInt();
       int m=sc.nextInt();
       //check for every number from 1 to N
       for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
         if(i==m){
               break;
           }
           //check if current number is prime
           if(isPrime(i)) {
             System.out.print(i + " ");
           }
       }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use that method but it will be slow for large numbers and you'll have to execute that code for every prime number query. If you have capacity and time, perhaps you could think about this technique instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes